# SEO Friendly URL display same id on different address - PHP

Tags: php

I have `index.php`, `portfolio/index.php`, `portfolio/post.php` and `.htaccess`files. 
**What is the status of the current code?** 
If you open my website `example.com` you will get a list of my portfolios. I have done small changes and gotten what I want. When the user clicks on my first added project, the user will be redirected to the directory `portfolio` and the URL will be for the project `Example 2` -> `example.com/portfolio/example-2`.
**What is the current problem?**
I have now added my second project and give him a name `Example 3` and now URL will be `example.com/portfolio/example-3`. The problem is when I open my newly added project, it will collect all details from my first entry or in this case from `Example 2`. Maybe the problem can be solved with added `$_GET['project_id']` or something like that, but I need help with this.
**Code for .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portfolio/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Code for example.com/index.php** -> This code is only for displaying all entries from a database and the second step is to open clicked project with all details.

```
<a href="portfolio/<?php echo htmlentities($project->link); ?>" title="<?php echo htmlentities($project->title); ?>">
    <span class="project__text"><?php echo htmlentities($project->title); ?></span>
</a>
```

***NOTE**:* 
In the database, `$link` is defined as `URL of the project`. So in this case `$link` data will get project slug `example-3` or `example-2`.
**Code for example.com/portfolio/index.php** -> This page have same code as `example.com/index.php` is just for display all portfolios projects registered in the database.
**Code for example.com/portfolio/post.php** -> This page need's to collect all from specific `ID` / selected `ID` and display to visitors.

```
$link = null;
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $link = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
if (null === $link) {
    header('index');
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE link = :link";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $project = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cnt = 1;
}
```

Where can be a problem? If you maybe need information how I call let's say `title` or `description` from database, i use `<?php echo $project['title'];?>` to display project details in current page `example.com/portfolio/example-3`. So, everything is working fine, just we need to resolve the issue/bug in the current code. So when the user wants to see details from `example.com/portfolio/example-2` to read all details that belong to that project.  Please, read carefully the question, there is all information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to this issue. In page `example.com/portfolio/post.php` update code from:

```
$link = null;
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $link = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
if (null === $link) {
    header('index');
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE link = :link";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $project = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cnt = 1;
}
```

to:

```
$link = null;
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $link = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
if (null === $link) {
    header('index');
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE link = :link";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    /**
     *
     * The array(':link' => $_GET['id']);
     *
    */
    $query->execute(array(':link' => $_GET['id']));
    $project = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cnt = 1;
}
```

Comment: Using `bindParam()` and passing an array to `execute()` should be mutually exclusive. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the original code

Comment: If you check the answer you will see what is the problem. Without update ```$query->execute(array(':link' => $_GET['id']));``` on different pages content will be the same, now it's resolved :) @Phil